# Modal dialog box with fading background?

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, fading

In my WPF application, when there is no user activity for 2 minutes, the application logs off.

I need to show the login box in the silverlight style (Background fades off). How can this be accomplished in WPF?

Comment: This has been asked *many* times, sadly it's rather hard to find things on this site...

Comment: The related questions houses some of the answers ;)

Comment: how about using adorner layer? any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right using adorner you can do this.

there are many articles there.. try these

http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2009/12/web-style-wpf-popup.html

http://bignickolson.com/2009/10/15/overlaying-controls-in-wpf-with-adorners/

Regards.